# Camel SQL Component with Simple Expression

Tags: spring, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am trying to implement a function like a HTTP proxy with Apache Camel.
In my proxy, I want to insert a header value in DB, and I used Simple Expression in SQL.

Here is my camel route.

```
<route>
    <from uri="servlet:///foo" />
    <to uri="sql:INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (TEST_ID, NAME) 
        VALUES(:#${header.testId}, 'test')?noop=true&amp;dataSource=testDataSource" />
    <to uri="http4://localhost:8080/test/bar?bridgeEndpoint=true" />
</route>
```

I was able to insert a header value, but I lost request body after SQL endpoint in this route.
And a response was 400.

The exception is

```
HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8080/test/bar with statusCode: 400
```

I found that the cause is Simple Expression.
However, I don't know why Simple Expression remove a request body, and how I can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem.

The cause is a type of request body.

http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html